# Is there a way i can upload a file as attatchement/File and use that file to on multiple records

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment

There is a document that the user uploads using a VF page and i want that file to be associated with multiple records. 
Currently we are creating multiple attachment records. ie if there are three records with reference to this document then it creates three instances of attachment which i feel is waste of storage space and more maintenance.

Is there a way to upload a document into a central place and use that link in the attachment related list.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a object (mediator) and linked all attachment to that object and now linked that object to All object which you want. it will save your time.

Because we can't create fields on attachment so I think this is a good option for you.